# Represent sum of random access iterators as a random access iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, pointer-arithmetic

Random access iterators are constrained to the difference between two iterators, or to adding or subtracting an integer from an iterator.
Rules do not allow addition of two iterators.

I stumbled on a situation where adding two iterators could actually be useful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;            using std::endl;

template<typename RndIterator> 
RndIterator rndIteratorsSum(RndIterator left, RndIterator right)
{
    //return (left + right) / 2;        // forbidden
    return left + (right - left) / 2;   // workaround
}
```

A sum of pointers has been reduced to a sum of a pointer + (`std::ptrdiff_t` / `int` = `int`) so it is legal now.
The test function could be:

```
int main()
{
// outputs median of input
    vector<int> test = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    vector<int>::iterator iter = rndIteratorsSum(test.begin(), test.end());
    
    cout << "median of input vector: " << *iter << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Is using the above trick allowed or discouraged? If discouraged, why?

Comment: In any modern C++ you'd have `auto` which is preferable to the `::iterator` junk necessitated in earlier standards.

Comment: For `std::vector` specifically or in general?

Comment: @tadman I am old-fashioned. In general.

Comment: In general this can't be done. Elements in `std::vector` are allocated in sequential memory, but this does not hold true for `std::list` or other non-array types. I'm not sure that `operator-` is even implemented for [those types of iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator).

Comment: @tadman Yes, of course. I meant in general for all sequential containers that employ Random Access Iterators (`vector`, `array`, `deque` in the STL, if I am not mistaken).

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the question. Is it asking if `return left + (right - left) / 2;` is legal?

Comment: Could dig through [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) to see if it's specifically clarified. It looks like the difference is supported but `/2`? Depends on the "difference type" involved. Is that `usize_t`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes, I fear it may look like bad practice

Comment: There is nothing wrong or tricky about `return left + (right - left) / 2;`

Comment: @Lingo There is nothing wrong with it. `(right - left) / 2` is clearly half the distance between `left` and `right`. You can use `std::distance(left, right) / 2` to self-document the intent.

Comment: `left + right` is forbidden because it may go out of bounds? `left + right / 2` should always be less than both iterators, so it wouldn't go out of bounds, so why is it forbidden?

Comment: @Lingo `left + right` is forbidden because it is meaningless. Iterators are modeled after pointers, where the same is true. Consider two arbitrary pointers. What is their sum? The only useful operation would be to sum their respective element's index within their shared array. But you cannot determine this information from two pointers alone. You first must subtract a pointer to the first element. In addition, iterators are more abstract. They can represent elements in containers more complex than an array or vector, like a linked list or an associative container like `std::map`.

Comment: `left` points at the beginning of a sequence; `right` points one-past-the-end of the sequence. If you could write `left + right`, what would its type be and what would it mean?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ok on all, except iterators in `std::map` and `std::list` will not allow pointer arithmetics: they are simpler versions than the random access iterators used for the array-type containers (they'd be bidirectional, or even just forward iterators for `std::forward_list`)

Comment: @PeteBecker `left + right` would be a type convertible to `int` in my head, but it should really be `left + ( right - begin() )` as I now understand, so we'd fall back to something implying distance as meaning of the sum-of-iterators operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking to allow `(left + right) / 2` as a shorter notation for `left + (right - left) / 2` because these expressions are equivalent for numbers in mathematics. However, to do that, you would need to define the addition of 2 iterators and division of iterator by a number. Neither of these operations seems to make sense on their own.

Comment: `right + left` has less of a clear meaning than the distance `right - left` but still may come useful in some situations, as shown in the question. Probably it is not allowed in order to avoid exceeding bounds of the container. But this forces inelegant workarounds the few times addition of pointers is effectively needed.

Comment: It is not specifically because of the resulting iterator being invalid. Just how would you define these operations? Consider a simpler case of a pointer (which is a special case of iterator). Could you define what a sum of 2 pointers means exactly?

Comment: given that we are in a sequential container, a sum of iterators would imply `iter = one_iter + some_other_iter`, in case I need to advance from `one_iter` of a number of positions that I cannot quantify as an `int`, but that I know is equal to the index of `some_other_iter`, which is another data position in my array.

Comment: @Lingo It is not possible to know the number of positions to add without knowing the position of each element, which requires subtracting them from a `begin()` iterator anyway. And `right + left` has no way of knowing what that `begin()` iterator is. It could only work if iterators were implemented by tracking the index of their element, which is not compatible with many containers and could never work with raw pointers with which iterator requirements must always be compatible, since pointers are a valid type of iterator.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Your reasoning makes sense, in that to sum iterators as a sort of `advance()`, that from iterator `left` moves a number of positions equal to `right`, tacitly presupposes really going forward of `right - begin()` places, which is a quantity compatible with an `int`. At that point you'd have `left + ( right - begin() )`, an `iterator + int`. This brings us back to the inelegant workaround I had in the question, but that shows with clarity there is a `iterator + (int) distance` operation involved in doing what I wanted to do. So yes, I follow you.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) spec you can have for iterators `a` and `b`:

- `a + b` is undefined.
- `a - b` yields `difference_type`, which is numerical (`n`)
- `a + n` yields an iterator

Therefore:

- `a + (a - b)` yields an iterator

If `difference_type` supports division, which it should, then you can also do `a + (a - b) / 2`.